# << Operator Rewrite to cout int and double values

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I need to rewrite the << operator so that it can cout values for hour (int) and temperature (double).

I think I've included all necessary sections. Thanks in advance.

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
    bool operator<(const Reading &r) const;
};
```

========

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Reading &r)
{
    // unsure what to enter here

    return ost;
}
```

========

```
vector<Reading> get_temps()
{
// stub version                                                                 
    cout << "Please enter name of input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist(name.c_str());
    if(!ist) error("can't open input file ", name);

    vector<Reading> temps;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    while (ist >> hour >> temperature){
        if (hour <0 || 23 <hour) error("hour out of range");
        temps.push_back( Reading(hour,temperature));
    }
```

}

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking us to write your function for you?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362077/c-operator-rewrite-to-cout-int-and-double-values There's no need to ask two of the same/similar question.

Comment: You're just duplicating your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362077/c-operator-rewrite-to-cout-int-and-double-values

Comment: Does the hour matter or does larger just mean temperature?

Comment: Please, don't put tags in the title, and don't ask the same question over and over again.  Use comments on answers to interact with their authors and edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 4):

For example like this:

```
bool operator <(Reading const& left, Reading const& right)
{
    return left.temperature < right.temperature;
}
```

And it should be a global function (or in the same namespace as `Reading`), not a member or `Reading`, it should be declared as a `friend` if you going to have any protected or private members.  This could be done like so:

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }

    friend bool operator <(Reading const& left, Reading const& right);
};
```

Comment: Make sure the operator definition goes in the same namespace the struct is in, so that it can be found during argument-dependent lookup.

Comment: Didn't think you can have a private member of a `struct` - wouldn't it have to be a `class`? In that case, yes, use `friend` so that the private/protected members may be accessed.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you expand on why you say it should not be a member function?

Comment: @Will: there is absolutely no difference between struct and class in C++, other than structs defaulting to `public`, and classes to `private`. But you can have private members in a struct just as easily as you can have public members of a class.

Comment: @jalf: thanks. I wasn't sure; I cannot remember ever using a `struct` for a type that has private data. To me, that was always the function of a class, though, as you say, the two are the same, save the default visibility level of their members.

Comment: ++ for that friend trick.  It's invaluable for creating an independent function and still keeping it in the namespace!

Comment: It could be a member (see what tmiddlet suggested).  There are two options available: global and member.  Member takes one parameter and a global one two.  But I think that this type of operator looks better when it's defined as a global function.  It makes more sense to me.

Comment: @detunized: From a readability standpoint, I would have to agree, seeing `operator< ( some_type x, some_type y )` may be more clear and make more sense when reading the code. I was just trying to find out if there was some standard or common practice that suggested one over the other. Perhaps just a matter of personal preference, then.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want something like

```
ost << r.hour << ' ' << r.temperature;
```

This is pretty simple stuff though, and if it doesn't make sense you should really talk to someone or get a book.

And if it still doesn't make sense or you can't be bothered, consider choosing another hobby/career.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, you can do it one of two ways ...

```
// overload operator<
bool operator< ( const Reading & lhs, const Reading & rhs )
{
  return lhs.temperature < rhs.temperature;
}
```

or, you can add the operator to your struct ...

```
struct Reading {
  int hour;
  double temperature;
  Reading ( int h, double t ) : hour ( h ), temperature ( t ) { }
  bool operator< ( const Reading & other ) { return temperature < other.temperature; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ost parameter like std::cout in operator<<.

Answer (score 2):

```
r.hour()
r.temperature()
```

You've declared `hour` and `temperature` as member *fields* of `Reading`, not member *methods*.  Thus they are simply `r.hour` and `r.temperature` (no `()`).

Answer (score 1):

As hour and temperature are variables rather than functions, just remove the trailing `()` from the `operator<<` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload an operator like this in c++.

```
struct Reading {
     int hour;
     double temperature;
     Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
     bool operator<(struct Reading &other) {
         //do your comparisons between this and other and return a value
     }
}
```