# << Operator Rewrite. Error from struct "cannot be used as a function"

Tags: c++, iostream, cout, ostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: << Operator Rewrite to cout int and double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362077/c-operator-rewrite-to-cout-int-and-double-values)

I need to rewrite the << operator so that it can cout values for hour (int) and temperature (double).

I think I've included all necessary sections. The section in question is the ostream& operator<<

It gives me error:

```
proj4.cc:87: error: ‘r->Reading::hour’ cannot be used as a function
proj4.cc:88: error: ‘r->Reading::temperature’ cannot be used as a function
```

Can I simply rewrite them as r.hour and r.temperature?

Thanks.

=================

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
    bool operator<(const Reading &r) const;
};
```

========

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ost, const Reading &r)
{
    return ost << '(' << r.hour()
               << ',' << r.temperature() <<')';

}
```

========

```
vector<Reading> get_temps()
{                                                             
    cout << "Please enter name of input file name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    ifstream ist(name.c_str());
    if(!ist) error("can't open input file ", name);

    vector<Reading> temps;
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    while (ist >> hour >> temperature){
        if (hour <0 || 23 <hour) error("hour out of range");
        temps.push_back( Reading(hour,temperature));
    }
```

}